# Emscripten_set_main_loop not working -- usleep undefined?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, emscripten

My project is compiling and opening up on the web but the main loop is not working. The error seems to be that usleep is undefined. I'm not sure how I can correct this. As per the error message, I seem to be dividing by zero (undefined). I tried removing 'fps' but no luck.

```
#define emscripten_set_main_loop(func,fps,simulateInfiniteLoop) 
while (1) { func(); usleep(1000000/fps); }

Expands to:

while (1) { loop(); usleep(1000000/0); }
identifier "usleep" is undefined C/C++(20)
```

Comment: Where are you expecting `usleep` to be defined? What header are you including to declare it?

Comment: `usleep` requires `#include <unistd.h>` on POSIX machines and does not exist on most other machines.  If you want your code to generally _work on machines_, use C++'s [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: @Brian: I'm using the standard emscripten.h file, which is identical to the following: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/kripken/emscripten/+/1.35.20/system/include/emscripten/emscripten.h

Comment: It is also important to understand what it means for a symbol to be "undefined".  It has nothing to do with dividing by zero.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I replaced usleep with sleep_for and added chrono and thread as header files. Still having the same error message, but now with sleep_for instead of usleep. :(

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question instead of an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I switched over to using emscripten_set_main_loop_arg, put all my variables in a struct, and rewrote my functions to accept pointers to the struct and deal appropriately.